# testing maven plugin, project.build.directory property for test project

Tags: groovy, maven-plugin

I'm trying to test my maven plugin.

The layout is:

src

\main\java\my.mojo.is.here

.....\it\invoke-installer-write-to-file\src\pom.xml

where **.....\it\invoke-installer-write-to-file\src\pom.xml** is a test project. it's pom.xml invokes plugin and then I do verify the result.

I've created two test projects and using maven-invoker-plugin to test plugin.
I have a groovy verifier:

```
String successMessage = 'Test passed'
String outputFilePath = "${project.build.directory}/it/invoke-installer-write-to-file/target/test.output"
File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath)

println "We should get message '$successMessage' from file: $outputFile.absolutePath"
return new File(outputFilePath).exists() && new File(outputFilePath).text.contains(successMessage)
```

The problem is that variable **project.build.directory** inside test project points to the target of plugin project.

Is there any possibility to make **project.build.directory** point to test project target?

right now I have to hardcode a path to test project path

```
String outputFilePath = "${project.build.directory}/it/invoke-installer-write-to-file/target/test.output"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String successMessage = 'Test passed'
String outputFilePath = "$basedir/target/test.output"
File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath)

println "We should get message '$successMessage' from file: $outputFile.absolutePath"
return new File(outputFilePath).exists() && new File(outputFilePath).text.contains(successMessage)
```

I did find this one: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html

basedir points to the root of test project. Now I'm happy.